# List operations related to another list's conditions

Tags: c#, linq, list, indexing

I have two lists like these:

```
public static List<List<List<double>>> listQ = new List<List<List<double>>>();
public static List<List<List<double>>> listVal = new List <List<List<double>>>();
```

[image]

2 list also have same size. I want some operations in listQ relation to listVal:

- if listVal's any indexes have same values, I want to take average listQ's values in same indexes.

For example:

```
listVal[0][0][ 1] = listVal[0][0][2] = 3.
```

So, I want listQ's same indexes be same.

```
(listQ[0][0][ 1] + listQ[0][0][2]) / 2 = (26.5 + 20.4) / 2 = 23.45.
```

Now, each these indexes must have 23.45 :

```
listQ[0][0][ 1] = 23.45

listQ[0][0][ 2] = 23.45
```

Likewise;

`listVal[0][2][0] = listVal[0][2][2] = 1`. Therefore `listQ[0][2][0] and listQ[0][2][2]` 's average must be taken.

How can I do this?

EDIT : @Roman Izosimov 's and @Petko Petkov 's solutions are working correctly. Which one has higher performance? What do you think?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LINQ solutions for lulz :)

```
List<List<List<double>>> listVal = new List<List<List<double>>>(){
    new List<List<double>>{
        new List<double>(){1,1,3},
        new List<double>(){2,1,2},
        new List<double>(){1,2,3}
    },
    new List<List<double>>{
        new List<double>(){2,1,3},
        new List<double>(){2,4,2},
        new List<double>(){3,1,3}
    },
    new List<List<double>>{
        new List<double>(){4,1,1},
        new List<double>(){4,2,1},
        new List<double>(){4,3,1}
    }
};
List<List<List<double>>> listQ = new List<List<List<double>>>(){
        new List<List<double>>{
        new List<double>(){3,7,4},
        new List<double>(){8,15,23},
        new List<double>(){11,13,17}
    },
    new List<List<double>>{
        new List<double>(){90,3,7},
        new List<double>(){5,7,12},
        new List<double>(){7,14,21}
    },
    new List<List<double>>{
        new List<double>(){32,4,1},
        new List<double>(){55,12,8},
        new List<double>(){3,5,8}
    }
};


//Linq awesomeness
var qry = listVal.SelectMany((l1, i0) =>
                l1.SelectMany((l2, i1) =>
                    l2.Select((ele, i2) =>
                        new { i0, i1, i2, gVal = ele, qVal = listQ[i0][i1][i2] })))
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.i0, x.i1, x.gVal }) // if you want to average across the innermost lists only 
                //.GroupBy(x => x.gVal)                   //if you want to average acreoss the whole data
                .SelectMany(x => x.Select(e => new { e.i0, e.i1, e.i2, avg = x.Average(y => y.qVal) }));
foreach (var e in qry)
{
    listQ[e.i0][e.i1][e.i2] = e.avg;
}
```

Comment: I prepared an image (http://i.hizliresim.com/xJprRq.png) contains listviews. Last listview has correct listQ. Same index's averages..

Comment: Update your question. From this picture it looks like you are averaging of the elements in the innermost lists only, while my and vutran's solutions asume you want average across all values in the whola data structure.

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is similar to count the frequences of elements in a list.
Your can use a `Dictionary<double,List<int[]>` with the `double` key is value in listVal, and `List<int[]>` stores the positions of that value in listVal.

Here my sample code:

```
//we store list of indices with the same value in a dictionary
Dictionary<double, List<int[]>> dictionary = new Dictionary<double, List<int[]>>();

//loop over listVal
for (int i = 0; i < listVal.Count; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < listVal[i].Count; j++)
        for (int k = 0; k < listVal[i][j].Count; k++)
        {
            if (!dictionary.ContainsKey(listVal[i][j][k]))
            {
                //if the dictionary doesn't have value listVal[i][j][k] 
                //then add the value as key with the value's current index
                dictionary.Add(listVal[i][j][k], new List<int[]> { new int[] { i, j, k } });
            }
            else
            {
                //add more index of the same value to the index list
                dictionary[listVal[i][j][k]].Add(new int[] { i, j, k });
            }
        }

foreach (var entry in dictionary)
{
    //get list of all position having the same value
    List<int[]> indices = entry.Value;

    //do your process on listQ
    //sum values in listQ
    double sum = 0;
    foreach (var index in indices)
    {
        sum += listQ[index[0]][index[1]][index[2]];
    }
    //calculate average value
    double average = sum / indices.Count;

    //assign back to litsQ
    foreach (var index in indices)
    {
        listQ[index[0]][index[1]][index[2]]  = average;
    }


}
```

Comment: This is not useful. Lists can have 1 or more indexes. So, listQ[0] is wrong. According to situation, listQ can has 3. index -> listQ[3].

Answer (score 3):

In my solution you can have any numbers of elements in `List<double>` in `listQ` and `listVal`, but in both lists elements count mus be same.

Algorithm:

```
for (var i1 = 0; i1 < listVal.Count; i1++)
            for (var i2 = 0; i2 < listVal[i1].Count; i2++)
            {
                var alreadyInList = new Dictionary<double, List<Tuple<int, int, int>>>();
                for (var d = 0; d < listVal[i1][i2].Count; d++)
                {
                    var decVal = listVal[i1][i2][d];
                    if (!alreadyInList.ContainsKey(decVal))
                    {
                        alreadyInList.Add(decVal, new List<Tuple<int, int, int>>());
                        continue;
                    }
                    var firstMatchElIndex = listVal[i1][i2].IndexOf(decVal);
                    if (alreadyInList[decVal].All(x => x.Item3 != firstMatchElIndex))
                        alreadyInList[decVal].Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(i1, i2, firstMatchElIndex));

                    alreadyInList[decVal].Add(new Tuple<int, int, int>(i1, i2, d));
                }

                SetListQ(listQ, alreadyInList.Where(x => x.Value.Count > 1).Select(x => x.Value));
            }

private void SetListQ(List<List<List<double>>> listQ, IEnumerable<List<Tuple<int, int, int>>> matches)
    {
        foreach (var match in matches)
        {
            var sum = match.Sum(tuple => listQ[tuple.Item1][tuple.Item2][tuple.Item3]);
            var avg = sum / match.Count;
            foreach (var tuple in match)
                listQ[tuple.Item1][tuple.Item2][tuple.Item3] = avg;
        }
    }
```

And check:

```
Console.WriteLine("listQ[0][0][0] = {0}", listQ[0][0][0]);
Console.WriteLine("listQ[0][0][1] = {0}", listQ[0][0][1]);
Console.WriteLine("listQ[0][0][2] = {0}", listQ[0][0][2]);
//....
```

Using your data:

```
var listQ = new List<List<List<double>>>
        {
            new List<List<double>>
            {
                new List<double>{20.9, 26.5, 20.4},
                new List<double>{18.3, 19.7, 22.2},
                new List<double>{12.7, 20.6, 25.6},
                new List<double>{17.1},
                new List<double>{17.3},
                new List<double>{16.9}
            }
        };

        var listVal = new List<List<List<double>>>
        {
            new List<List<double>>
            {
                new List<double>{1, 3, 3},
                new List<double>{1, 3, 3},
                new List<double>{1, 3, 1},
                new List<double>{1},
                new List<double>{3},
                new List<double>{3}
            }
        };
```

We have in Console:

```
listQ[0][0][0] = 20.9
listQ[0][0][1] = 23.45
listQ[0][0][2] = 23.45
listQ[0][1][0] = 18.3
listQ[0][1][1] = 20.95
listQ[0][1][2] = 20.95
listQ[0][2][0] = 19.15
listQ[0][2][1] = 20.6
listQ[0][2][2] = 19.15
```

For example I added some additional data:

```
var listQ = new List<List<List<double>>>
        {
            new List<List<double>>
            {
                new List<double>{20.9, 26.5, 20.4, 10.0},
                new List<double>{18.3, 19.7, 22.2, 12.22},
                new List<double>{12.7, 20.6, 25.6, 20.6},
                new List<double>{17.1},
                new List<double>{17.3},
                new List<double>{16.9}
            }
        };

        var listVal = new List<List<List<double>>>
        {
            new List<List<double>>
            {
                new List<double>{1, 3, 3, 1},
                new List<double>{1, 3, 3, 3},
                new List<double>{1, 3, 1, 2},
                new List<double>{1},
                new List<double>{3},
                new List<double>{3}
            }
        };
```

After processing we have:

```
listQ[0][0][0] = 15.45
listQ[0][0][1] = 23.45
listQ[0][0][2] = 23.45
listQ[0][0][3] = 15.45
listQ[0][1][0] = 18.3
listQ[0][1][1] = 18.04
listQ[0][1][2] = 18.04
listQ[0][1][3] = 18.04
listQ[0][2][0] = 19.15
listQ[0][2][1] = 20.6
listQ[0][2][2] = 19.15
listQ[0][2][3] = 20.6
```

This is not whery nice solution but it works and use minimum iterations count. I hope this solution will solve your task.

Comment: Thanks for your attention. This solution is also working fine.